# How to print/display the output of a telnet session and print out in the file as well - Python

Tags: python, telnetlib

I'm facing a pretty simple error here.
I need to connect in some devices reading a file hosts.txt and print out the output in the files .txt, but I also need to read in the windows terminal.

Here is the script:

```
import sys
import telnetlib

user = "xxx"
password = "xxx"

file = open("hosts.txt", "r")
for line in file:

        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(line)
        tn.read_until("Username: ")
        tn.write(user + "\n")
        tn.read_until("Password: ")
        tn.write(password + "\n")
        tn.write("enable \n")
        tn.write(password + "\n")
        ##
        tn.write("dir\n")
        tn.write("exit \n")
        ##
        output = tn.read_until("exit")
        print output
        ##
        #sys.stdout=open(line + ".txt","w")
        #print tn.read_all()
        #sys.stdout.close()
```

Here I can see in the terminal but when I uncomment the lines to write the output on files (last 3 lines), I get the following error, stoping in the first "host":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dir.py", line 26, in ?
    print output
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
[noctemp@svcactides check_ios]$
```

How can I print the output in the screen AND in the file at the same time?

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reassigning `sys.stdout` is a terrible idea.

After the first iteration, you've lost the actual stdout object and then close the file you've replaced it with, resulting in the given error when you try to write to it in the next iteration of the loop.

Instead, use `print` to print to stdout, and open a *separate* file object and write to that:

```
output = tn.read_until("exit")
print output
##
with open(line + ".txt","w") as f:
  f.write(output)
```

Comment: I think I get you point, but now its a syntax error:

  File "dir.py", line 33
    with open(line + ".txt","w") as f:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[noctemp@svcactides check_ios]$

Comment: @Thiago: That doesn't seem right... are you using an archaic version of Python? Bad indentation?

Comment: Now it's working! I just adjusted the variables and it's working as I wanted! Thanks @Linuxios !

Comment: @thiago: great! Glad I could help! If an answer solved your problem, it's good on StackOverflow to mark the green checkbox so others know the problem has been solved ("accepting an answer"). Good luck with all your programming!

Answer (score 0):

the question was solved, the final script is this:

```
import sys
import telnetlib

user = "xx"
password = "xx"

file = open("hosts.txt", "r")
for line in file:

        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(line)
        tn.read_until("Username: ")
        tn.write(user + "\n")
        tn.read_until("Password: ")
        tn.write(password + "\n")
        tn.write("enable \n")
        tn.write(password + "\n")

        tn.write("dir\n")
        tn.write("sh run | i boot\n")
        tn.write("exit \n")

        output =  tn.read_until("exit")
        print output

        stdout=open(line + ".txt","w")
        stdout.write(output)
```

Thankx all!